# Trouble Importing XML File into SQL Server Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, import

Sample XML below. Using the code below to import XML but the SELECT is just not finding the values.

```
SELECT
    MY_XML.varname.query('NAME').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),
    MY_XML.varname.query('description').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),
    MY_XML.varname.query('username').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),
    MY_XML.varname.query('DRIVER').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),
    MY_XML.varname.query('url').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(300)')
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CAST(MY_XML AS xml)
        FROM
            OPENROWSET(BULK 'S:\TEMP\neo-datasource.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)
    ) AS T (MY_XML)
    CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes(
        '/wddxPacket/data/array/struct/var/struct/var/name'
    ) AS MY_XML (varname);
```

[XML][image: 1]

Comment: You need to post some sample data (i.e. a [mre]) for us to assist.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the *inner text* of nodes which have particular *attributes*, **the predicate is not on the node name itself.** So you need a predicate on the node `[]`, and then take the inner `text()`.

---

**You are misunderstanding how `.query` and `.value` work.**

- `.query` just returns a particular XML node matching the XQuery
- `.value` returns a single value from XQuery, typed to a certain data type

There is no need to use both together

---

Furthermore, you appear to be shredding two levels too far with `.nodes`, as you seem to want these values in a single row.

```sql
SELECT
    MY_XML.varname.value('(var[@name="NAME"       ]/string/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),
    MY_XML.varname.value('(var[@name="description"]/string/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),
    MY_XML.varname.value('(var[@name="username"   ]/string/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),
    MY_XML.varname.value('(var[@name="DRIVER"     ]/string/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),
    MY_XML.varname.value('(var[@name="url"        ]/string/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(300)')
    -- ,MY_XML.varname.value('(parent::./@name)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(300)')
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CAST(MY_XML AS xml)
        FROM
            OPENROWSET(BULK 'S:\TEMP\neo-datasource.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)
    ) AS T (MY_XML)
    CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes(
        '/wddxPacket/data/array/struct/var/struct'
    ) AS MY_XML (varname);
```

Comment: I would have never figured out that T-SQL. I need to get better at XML. I run your version and get Msg 2389, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
XQuery [T.MY_XML.value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

Comment: BYW thanks Dale for taking the time out to explain what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Hmm no errors but still doesn't work. I've seen this with different versions of the T-SQL I've tried to craft. Returns NULL for all columns in the result set of the select.

Comment: Hum looking at it again the actual value is the inner text of the child `string` node, have fixed now. It would be much easier if you [edit] and add the actual XML *as text* in your question

Comment: That worked! Thanks very much. Tucking that knowledge away for future use.